# how to get the id of the current user in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

i try to get the userId and the event ID to insert into ReservatonEvenement table in database but it give me an error of :Argument #1 ($ID_user) must be of type ?App\Entity\User, int given.
and when i do vardump ($this->getUser()->getId() ) i got the id of user but with an int() like int(2)

----------------------------ReservationEvenementController-----------------------
/**
* @param Request $request
* @return Response
* @Route("/n/d", name="app_res")
*/
public function Reserver(Request $request): Response
{

```
    $user = new User();
    $evenement= new Evenement();
    $reservationEvenement = new ReservationEvenement();
    $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
    var_dump(  $id);
    var_dump($user->getId());
    
    $reservationEvenement->setIDUser($id);

    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($reservationEvenement);
    $em->flush();`enter code here`

    return new Response('Event Add it Succusfully ');
}
```

---

this the ReservationEvent.php entity

```
    **
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ReservationEvenementRepository::class)
 */
class ReservationEvenement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="reservationEvenements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ID_user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Evenement::class, inversedBy="reservationEvenements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ID_evenement;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIDUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->ID_user;
    }

    public function setIDUser(?User $ID_user): self
    {
        $this->ID_user = $ID_user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIDEvenement(): ?Evenement
    {
        return $this->ID_evenement;
    }

    public function setIDEvenement(?Evenement $ID_evenement): self
    {
        $this->ID_evenement = $ID_evenement;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and this is the class diagrame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB5v5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`$reservationEvenement->setIDUser($this->getUser());`

Explanation: as stated in the error message, the method `setIDUser` expect a User object as a parameter, but you are feeding it with an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the user entity, as Musa answered:

`$reservationEvenement->setIDUser($this->getUser())`;

That is because the property is relation to other table. This is explained very well in symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/associations.html#saving-related-entities